# Simple Question on Binomial theorems...

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image]
I have tried to solve this question by putting the value of each coefficients but it is really becoming very lengthy....
what i got was this number 10510100501...
But how to get this in the required form??
Please help me...
Also is there any other elegant way to solve this question...Any help would be appreciated.. Moreover what i had figured out was that the each numeric terms that are premultiplied are actually the coefficients of the binomial expansion of (1-x)^5....
Thanks in advance...........$(value of n is 101)$..

Comment: My neck hurts now, why can't you type it?

Comment: Note that since $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$, there is no unique answer to this problem.

Comment: If this is a "simple question", as you say, why do you ask it here?

Comment: It is ironic, that the only thing texed here is something that shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&\binom{505}{5}-5\binom{404}{5}+10\binom{303}{5}-10\binom{202}{5}+5\binom{101}{5}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{5}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{5}{k}\binom{101k}{5}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{5}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{5}{k}\binom{101k}{5}\\&=-\sum_{k=0}^{5}(-1)^{k}\binom{5}{k}\binom{101k}{5}\\&=-\sum_{k=0}^{5}(-1)^{k}\binom 5k(1+x)^{101k}\qquad [x^5]\\&=-\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom 5k\cdot 1^{5-k}\cdot(-(1+x)^{101})^k\qquad [x^5]\\&=-(1-(1+x)^{101})^5\qquad [x^5]\\&=-(1-(1+x))^5(1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+\cdots +(1-x)^{100})^5\qquad [x^5]\\&=(1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+\cdots +(1-x)^{100})^5\qquad [x^0]\\&=101^5\end{align}$$

Comment: Since 5 is prime, $\lambda=5$ but what about $n,r$ ?